# Что под капотом Insert, Commit tran?

Tags: sql-server, transaction

Я изучаю механизм транзакций в ms sql. В документации к журналу транзакций сказано: "Исходный образ записи - это копия данных до выполнения операции". Как эти данные из журнала используются при фиксации транзакции?

Например, есть такой код:

```
begin tran
insert to ...
commit tran
```

Что происходит с данными под капотом, когда выполняется "insert", кроме записи в журнал транзакций?

Что происходит, когда вы выполняете "commit"? Данные каким-то образом перемещаются из журнала в таблицу или они уже находятся в таблице и просто помечаются как зафиксированные?

Где можно прочитать об этой механике? В том числе об откатах транзакций и т.д.

upd: вопрос исключительно про то как меняются данные

Comment: Я бы к Вашему вопросу добавил еще пункт "уровни изоляции транзакций".

Comment: S.H., как именно уровни изоляции могут дополнить мой вопрос?

Comment: Гугл по "sql server процесс записи" нашел довольно интересную статью https://habr.com/ru/post/579018/

Comment: @vi0 - я посоветовал это исключительно потому, что этот вопрос часто задаётся на собеседованиях, наверное, это действительно далеко от Вашего вопроса. тогда - прошу прощения!

Answer (score 0):

[По ссылке](https://habr.com/ru/post/579018/) из комментариев есть хорошее описание процесса. Тут я опишу самое главное и, надеюсь, более удобоваримо:

1. Данные хранятся постранично. Сначала страница, в которую будет произведена запись, загружается в память с диска. Хранятся такие страницы в так называемом Buffer pool - это по сути кеш данных с диска. Кеш в том смысле, что он хранит данные временно, чтоб не нужно было каждое изменение записывать на диск или читать с диска сразу же (но дальше об этом подробнее).
2. Оператор изменения (в нашем случае `insert`) получает эксклюзивную блокировку на изменяемую страницу. Это означает, что ни один другой параллельный запрос не сможет считать изменяемую страницу.
3. Оператор изменения добавляет в лог транзакций запись, в точности описывающую, что и как оператор собирается изменить на этой странице. В нашем случае, он добит информацию, что собираюсь вставить запись с такими-то значениями колонок. При этом генерируется LSN (Log sequence number) – номер операции внутри лога транзакций.
4. После этого оператор изменяет страницу в памяти (т.е. Buffer pool). Страница на диске в этот момент не меняется!
5. LSN записывается в заголовок изменяемой страницы в поле «LSN последнего изменения» (last modified LSN)
6. Снимается эксклюзивная блокировка на страницу. Теперь страница может быть прочитана другими транзакциями (например, в режиме Read Uncommitted). Важно понимать, что до сих пор ни одного байта не было записано на диск – все изменения происходили в памяти.
7. Перед тем, как изменяющая транзакция будет завершена, она должна создать новую запись лога, фиксирующую факт, что транзакция зафиксирована (committed). Эта запись добавляется в лог транзакций и после этого она и все предшествующие записи лога (в рамках транзакции) записываются на диск – в файл лога транзакций. Изменяемая страница в этот момент всё еще не записана на диск, её изменения остаются только в памяти. Но сама транзакция с этого момента становится надёжной (durable): даже если служба SQL Server упадёт, информация об изменениях на странице хранятся в логе транзакций, процесс запуска БД прочитает её и повторит нужные действия.
8. Периодически (но не сразу по окончании транзакции) изменения в страницах из Buffer pool записываются на диск, в файл данных. Эта операция называется CHECKPOINT.

Фактически состояние БД в любой момент, это страницы, хранящиеся на диске + содержимое лога транзакций (опять же на диске). То что находится в памяти (т.е. Buffer pool) сервера, содержит незафиксированные транзакции и его можно терять без ущерба для durability.